# ViM iabbrev to Automatically Replace consecutive blank lines with a character

Tags: linux, vim

I was just wondering if it's possible to create a ViM rule for the following scenario.

If I am editing a file is it possible for iabbrev to detect a second blank line and insert some character or string into that lines place?

```
Typing in ViM *Newline*
*Newline*
*Newline*This is extra
*Newline*This is extra
```

I really hope this makes sense

Comment: Check out the [vi.se] Stack Exchange for questions on Vim.

Comment: Wow a whole stack exchange just for Vim, thanks a bunch that's really helpful